# Inconsistencies in Server Performance Arising from Infrastructure Configuration

Tags: .net, .net-core, newrelic, infrastructure, multi-instance-deployment

I am facing this kind of situation quite a few times. That when develop my application then running it on my local machine or development environment, there is no problem.
But after I deployed my application to UAT/PRODUCTION environment, sometimes got issues that the features were not working as expected (comparing with Local/Development).

For your context, the Local/Development Environment will be managed by team. But UAT/PROD is managed by our partner.

Here are 2 cases that I would like to share to seek for your support:

Example 1: When implementing IdentityServer4, we utilize the endpoint [endpoint]/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks to fetch keys for token validation. This works seamlessly in the Local/Development environment, ensuring successful token validation. However, upon transitioning to UAT, an issue arises: randomly, tokens are either validated successfully or rejected.

The root cause is traced back to our partner's setup of multiple instances on the server, accommodating performance and scalability. The challenge arises from two certificates uploaded to these servers, leading to the endpoint responding with two different key values. If a token generated by one instance is verified by the same instance, no issues occur. However, if verification happens on a different instance, the token is deemed invalid.

Fortunately, we resolved this by involving the development team to investigate both the source code and infrastructure setup.

Example 2: On server side, my parter setup a tool which is New Relic, on the development side, we upgrade an application to .NET 6. And same as above, on our Local/Development, we have never setup New Relic so no issue found. After UAT deployment, there are issues appeared. It took us (development team) a while to find out what was the issue, because they have use [an older version and that version did not support .NET 6](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/getting-started/net-agent-compatibility-requirements-net-core/).

My questions are:

- As my cases shared above, the development team lacked clarity on the server setup. Is there a way to enhance this situation, perhaps not just requesting the server infrastructure setup in advance?
- As a developer in the midst of development, how can I effectively pose a question on StackOverflow, specifying that I'm working on resolving an issue related to a multiple instances setup?
- If I want to explore additional cases that might pose issues with infrastructure setup, similar to the example mentioned earlier, are there specific hashtags, resources, or references on the internet, including Stack Overflow, that I can refer to?